# batchGet endpoint behavior with multiple photos

Tags: google-streetview-publish

I am testing the [photos.batchGet endpoint](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchGet).

Per the API docs, it takes two URL parameters "view" and "photoIds". When I try the photoIds parameter, the request only works with one photoId. Using multiple photoIds fails.

I tried using a delimeter between the photoIds in the string (by using a comma, pipe, and space). I also tried not using a delimeter at all. Not using a delimeter returns a response for the last photoId in the string, but not for any of the other photoIds. In short, none of my requests appear to be working. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, depending on server configuration, I think it's recommended for the URL length to be under 2,000 characters. Anything above 30 photoIds would create URLs longer than this.

That being said, maybe it would be better to make this a POST request that accepts a JSON request body? Just a thought, but think this would be better suited. A lot of our tours are above 30 scenes, and we even had a tour with 700 scenes!

Answer (score 0):

The description of the [batchGet](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchGet#query-parameters) function was updated. Per the documentation you should pass photoIds as a string and the URL query parameter should be `photoIds=<id1>&photoIds=<id2>`.